# DRF 3.0: UniqueTogetherValidator with a read-only field

Tags: django-rest-framework

In process of upgrading to Django REST Framework 3.0 from 2.4.4 and I want to have a read-only user field, but this is failing because 'user' is being required by the UniqueTogetherValidator (I think)

I have model (excuse typos, this is simplified and the code works fine IRL):

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    some_attr = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    other_attr = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('some_attr', 'other_attr', 'user')
```

Viewset:

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Serializer:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
```

Now, I keep getting errors saying: `{"user":["This field is required."]}`, which was not the case before. In a slightly different example with the same basic problem, I get the assertion error `May not set both 'read_only' and 'required'` even though I am not setting user as required.

I receive the same error regardless if I add `required=False` for the user attribute in the serializer, or if I add user to the the excluded fields in the serializer's meta.

When I use the handy new serializer printing, I see:

```
class Meta:
    validators = [UniqueTogetherValidator(queryset=ExampleModel.objects.all(), fields=('user', 'some_attr', 'other_attr'))]
```

which gets automatically added based on the model's unique_together. If I explicitly overwrite this and do not include 'user' in the fields for `UniqueTogetherValidator` then everything works as before.

Is this an intended consequence of the 3.0 update? Seems to me that adding `request.user` in the `perform_create` / `perform_update` is very standard DRF procedure as demonstrated in the tutorial. I realize not having the new validation just means failing at the DB level instead, and the new validation probably gives better error messages, but

**Is there a solution other than to override the validation for every serializer where this is an issue?**

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: hey, I'd be curious to know how you use the *handy serializer printing* as if I call `print repr(serializer)` as described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer) I don't see any data related to Meta. thanks! :)

Comment: For me, the only Meta info showing up is the validators. Also, as far as I can tell, you can just call `YourSerializer()` and the output is the same as `print repr(YourSerializer())`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2164) that we are in the process of addressing within Django REST Framework. As of right now, there is a note in the [documentation about UniqueTogtherValidator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator) that says

> **Note:** The `UniqueTogetherValidation` class always imposes an implicit constraint that all the fields it applies to are always treated as required. Fields with `default` values are an exception to this as they always supply a value even when omitted from user input.

This explains why you are seeing an error because the field is required, even though you are explicitly settings `read_only=True`. You may want to look into the [`CurrentUserDefault` class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault), which may suit your needs while avoiding the issue with the `UniqueTogetherValidator`.

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(
        read_only=True
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
```

This *should* do the same thing as your `perform_create` and `perform_update` hooks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, was just looking at the release notes and didn't see that documentation. `CurrentUserDefault` did the trick though! Thanks for the zippy response.

Comment: I don't think the `default` applies on `perform_update` — but normally/often you only need to set the user reference on create.

Comment: Sorry to necro the thread, but what's the suggested route to take if there are other default values that's being passed into the `.save()` method, other than CurrentUser?