# How to validate together-uniqueness of two (foreign key) related fields of a model?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have three models in my app that lets user write a review for a book. The requirement is that every user can only do one review for each book.

`Review` model has two foreign keys to `User` and `Book` models. I want to be able to validate user input before creating an instance of `Review` model to ensure a user can not create more than one review per book.

I know how to do it if I ask the user to provide the `User` and `Book` information in the data that's sent to DRF version 3.+.

But the url to post a new `Review` has the `Book` id in it, and the user is authenticated:

url used to `list` and `create` reviews: `/book/{book_id}/reviews/`

Right now when I do a `POST` operation on the url, DRF complains that the `book` field is required, even though I tried to send keyword arguments to the overloaded `perform_create` function (see snippets below)

My guess is I should send the information about book and review that's embedded in the url and `request` to the default `UniqueTogetherValidator` but I don't know how to do it!

I have seen a [partial solution in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239382/drf-3-0-uniquetogethervalidator-with-a-read-only-field), but my problem is that I not only have to provide the current authenticated user to the validator but also the `book` information, since I am requiring a `unique_together` constraint.

- I have unsuccessfully tried providing `default` kwarg to the fields.
- Also tried providing a custom validator in the serializer, which didn't succeed.

So my question is how to validate `unique_together` of input data from user's request when the `book` information is embedded in the `url` and the `user` information is part of the incoming `request` (while both of those are related foreign keys and not local attributes of `Review` model)?

Here are my models and serializers:

#### models.py

```py
class Review(models.Model):

    # Relationships
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "book"),)
```

#### serializers.py

```py
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    book = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
```

#### Part of views.py

```py
class ReviewList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, book=self.kwargs['book_id'])
```

#### urls.py

```py
url(r'^book/(?P<book_id>\d+)/reviews/$', view=ReviewList.as_view(), name='review-list')
```

Comment: Why you are using `meal` instead of `book` here? `unique_together = (("user", "meal"),)`

Comment: it is typo (fixed) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make things harder than they should.

My feeling on this issue is that the unique together constraint is part of the business rules. Therefore I'd go with removing that constraint on the serializer. After the serializer has validated the data you'll be able to check the constraint on the review (owner + book) and raise a validation error if there's already one. Doing this in the perform_create before saving the serializer seems sensible.

To remove the unique together constraint you'll have to explicitly set the validators on the serializer:

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    book = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        validators = []
```

Make sure to print a serializer instance before doing that change so you can make sure you're not removing other contraints.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, `ModelSerializer` of DRF automatically picks up the constrain from the model. Then since `request.data` doesn't have book or user, I get a validation error that they are required, even though they are declared `read_only`. It seems I have to override the validation process but not sure how, that's why I asked :)

Comment: thanks I used your suggestion and checked for the uniqueness in the `perform_create()` function. If I wanted to do this in the serializer by adding a validor to its `Meta` class, how would I filter the validator's `queryset` argument there since I don't have access to `request` info anymore

Comment: You can gain access to the request through the validator's `get_context` and serializer's context. Example for the default `UniqueTogetherConstraint` implementation: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/validators.py#L87